# htmleditorextender medium trust level alternative

Tags: asp.net, webforms, ajaxcontroltoolkit, htmleditorextender

I have been using the `ajaxcontroltoolkit htmleditorextender`, which on the development server worked fine but then when I uploaded to my *1and1* shared hosting it does not work. Seems to require a high/full trust level, which *1and1* do not allow on this package. They keep trying to get me to change to a dedicated server. Which unfortunately is not an option. I may be wrong but I get the impression *1and1* do this so that people will upgrade. I do not wish to and cannot, even if I wanted to, upgrade to the dedicated server package.

So my question is this... Is their a free alternative to the `ajaxcontroltoolkit htmleditorextender` that can run on trust level medium? Or, what would be even better, can I modify the `htmleditorexteder` to make it work on medium trust level?

I went with *1and1* in the first place because I was informed that they are reliable, cheap and have good customer service. The only one I have found to be true is the cheap part, and that's only if yo

I have endlessly googled this and the only suggestions I can find involve either changing hosting providers or accepting that my website will never work as I want it to. All the `htmleditorextender` alternatives I have found seem to run on full trust level, although I could be and probably am wrong. So any suggestions on what to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I built my own.
http://www.griffithswebdesign.com/TextEditor
I hope this helps somebody. It's pretty basic but it does everything I needed

Answer (score 3):

[TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/) is a client WYSIWYG HTML editor which will run at any trust level and perform similar tasks as Ajax Control Toolkit HtmlEditorExtender.